# Disable Alphabetic characters in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

in Flutter/Dart how can I disable all alphabetic characters while typing in a `TextFormField` ?
I want only Numbers to be shown when the user type inside the field.
Thank you.
Example : when user type : Test2094 , the only shown text is 2094. but it's not only about showing text but the stored information should be only numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try with keyboard type number only and user can able to input digits only and import `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```
          TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        signed: false,
                        decimal: false,
                      ),
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      ],
                      
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Number*",
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: Thank you , you just forgot to mention to import services.dart. It's working like a charm.

Comment: @LearningCode mentioned it. you are welcome.

Comment: please mark as answer did it work for you